# Merge 1d and 2d numpy arrays into a tuple

Tags: arrays, numpy, tuples

I have two numpy arrays here:

```
a = np.array([1, 2]) 
b = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
```

I'd like to merge them into a `tuple` so that `a`'s elements are vertical, like so:

```
[(1, [1, 2, 3]), (2, [4, 5, 6])]
```

Could you provide suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: If that's really what you're wanting, then `zip(a, b)` will do it.  What do you mean by "vertical", though? Are you wanting a "column vector"? (i.e. `x[:,None]`)

Comment: Your desired expression is a list of tuples, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#zip) fit the bill?

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2])
>>> b = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
>>> zip(a,b)
[(1, array([1, 2, 3])), (2, array([4, 5, 6]))]
```